# mysql select match multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that looks like.

```
user    project
----    -------
bob     news
bob     theatre
sarah   news
fred    news
fred    fred
fred    movies
sarah   movies
```

I am trying to pull a list of projects if the user is *never* `fred`

so the result based on the above table would be.

```
bob theatre
```

I am stumped on how to achieve this. I have a unique list of users in a another table I can join to. I can do this with a for loop in some language but I figure there must be a way to do this in native sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.* 
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.project = a.project and b.user = 'fred'
where b.user is null
```

For the rows you want, there *won't* be a joined row and the such rows will have `null` values, so the where clause filters out just those.

Comment: nice!! that works. I will accept this answer. I think I even get why it works. I was trying something similar without the null part.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to use the NOT EXISTS operator in your WHERE statement; something like:

```
Select P.* from Projects P Where NOT EXISTS (Select * from Projects P2 where P2.project = P.project and P2.user = 'fred')
```

A second possibility would be to use the NOT IN operator:

```
Select P.* from Projects P Where P.project NOT IN (Select P2.project from Projects P2 where P2.user = 'fred')
```

This is for Microsoft SQL-Server; however, this should run unmodified on MySQL.

Comment: Performance is not good with `exists()`. Only use it when you have to - joins are usually preferred. Although, I grant you they are easier to understand

Comment: I agree with you that performance is not always the best when using a EXISTS() but I don't think that this will ever be of concern here with this kind of data.